# A question about how to define Silow $p$-subgroups and maximal p-subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

I will start by the following example.

If I study a group of order 8, are their Sylow's subgroups of order 8 or 4?

For example for $\mathbf{Q}_{8}$, the maximal p-subgroups are of order 4, $\mathbf{C}_{4}$, and there are 3 of this subgroups, isomorphics between them, $3{\equiv}_{2}1$ but $\forall n \; 3{\nmid}2^n$). Too, $\forall x \in \mathbf{Q}_{8} xix^{-1}\in \langle i\rangle \Leftrightarrow \langle i\rangle\lhd\mathbf{Q}_{8}$, and by this way, $\{\langle i\rangle ,\langle j\rangle ,\langle k\rangle \}$ are not conjugate between them.

Then, my answer is that for a group of order $p^n$ its unique Sylow $p$-subgroup is itself, if assuming the previous example as counterexample, resulting that it is not the same Sillow's $p$-subgroups and maximal $p$-subgroups.

If I admit that a maximal subgroups can be the self whole group, then for a $p$-group, its Silow subgroup is the maximal subgroup and it is itself.

The problem for me is the definition of maximal subgroup, beacuse in ring theory a maximal ideal is a proper ideal and I belived a maximal soubgroup only can be a proper subgroup.

Which is the definition of maximal subgroup?

Comment: You got your definition wrong: Sylow $p$-subgroups are maximal (in the sense of order and not in the sense of subgroup) $p$-subgroups, so in particular when a group it self is a $p$-group, this group is THE Sylow $p$-subgroup. In general, a Sylow subgroup does not have to be a maximal subgroup.

Comment: I know that I have not understood the definition of Silow $p$-subgroups, but the problem is that a maximal subgroup I understand is a proper subgroup, and by this, the whole group can not be a maximal subgroup. This idea is from ideals and maximal ideals in ring theory, but it looks the same definition don't keep in both subjects.

Comment: Forget about maximal subgroups, this is about maximal orders.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for reading this silly question and lose time answered me. Thank you.

Comment: "maximal" only includes proper when taken alone. Once we add other properties, we no longer include proper if the full group does not automatically satisfy these properties

Comment: Thank you. You say that the concept of maximal subgroup is clearly defined when we talk about the subgroup lattice only, in the case I mentioned and others, the concept of maximal subgroup maps to subgroup of maximal order. It is correct?